# Recent search drop down location on Win10

Tags: windows-10, windows-search

With Win7 the recent search drop down within Explorer appeared right where you typed the text of your search. With Win10 its way off in the distance. Is there a way to move it back to where it used to be?
[image]

Comment: You would have to replace File Explorer to accomplish this goal.  There are many alternatives that might function the way you want it to

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 (Most elegant but time consuming): Edit your registry. A great article to get you started at https://mspoweruser.com/registry-hack-allows-users-to-enable-task-bar-search-box-in-windows-10-build-9879/

Option 2: A third party file explorer. Lots of options out there to "explore" ;)

Option 3: Get used to the present Win10 layout, in a month or two your mouse muscle memory might just make this a non issue.